# PHP Video Url with GET

Tags: php, url, variables, video, get

So I have a video player with the following source code.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src=<?php echo $tryOne; ?> type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It will echo something something similar to below and insert it as the source video.

```
'176.227.210.66/Kuroko%20no%20Basket%202%20Episode%205.mp4?st=zEws3h1Xg-to07f3as6KqA&e=1385059955'
```

However, the player will not load the the video. If I open page source and copy the generate url into the address bar and hit enter, it will go to the direct url and load the video just fine. I think that the player won't load the url because it has GET variables in it, and I need to know how to fix this. Please tell me how I can load a video in a player from the above url with GET variables.

Note: the player will load a video just fine if it is named without the get variables.

Comment: Are you sure it is an MP4?

Comment: In my experience, the video tag is very picky about file format as well as type.  Just my 2 cents.  Another way to verify that the problem isn't just a missing "http://" is to put the whole thing in as plain html and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [HTML specification for `<video>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html#video.attrs.src), you need a valid URL:

> **src** = non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces.
>   The URL for the video.

In this case, it is missing the protocol information (`http://`) and it is not being recognized as a video src. Change the value of `$tryOne` to include the protocol information or manually prepend it to the variable when outputting to the page. It might also be a good idea to URL-encode the string.

For example:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src=<?php echo 'http://'.urlencode($tryOne); ?> type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/xcHbW/embedded/result/)

Comment: this is most probably the answer. Browser adds it when typing the URL in the address bar, but obviously not in source... I would put in the variable though instead of the echo cause in this case the protocol could be part of the address from where I see it

Comment: @Bartdude: Yeah, adding `http://` should fix the issue. I've updated the answer with a demo to prove this point. :)